# Why should I use select with pipe in Angular subscribe?

Tags: angular, select, rxjs, pipe, store

I was reading the docs of angular and its use of RxJS library. 
And I found this info

**[Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators)**

> You can use pipes to link operators together. Pipes let you combine
>   multiple functions into a single function. The pipe() function takes
>   as its arguments the functions you want to combine, and returns a new
>   function that, when executed, runs the composed functions in sequence.

So the purpose of piping is to chain multiple functions, but what made me curious is that I have seen many times the use of `pipe` with only one function inside, eg:

```
this.itemSubscription = this.store
            .pipe(select(state => state.items.root))
            .subscribe(state => {
                this.items = state.items;
            });
```

When I try to use `select` without `pipe`, then my tslint says:

> select is deprecated: from 6.1.0. Use the pipeable select operator
>   instead. (deprecation)tslint(1)

Why is that happening? Am I missing something? Could not find any relevant explanation on the Internet.

Comment: Even when there is only one operator to apply, you must apply it using pipe(). Operators are functions, not methods of Observable.

Comment: `pipe()` accepts up to ten operator functions so using `.pipe(select(...))` just `pipe()` with one operator which is perfectly correct.

Comment: (1) RxJS moved to pipable operators with version 6, dot-chained operators are no longer supported. If you want to know why read this: [pipeable-operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#why). (2) NgRx first deprecated `store.select` in 6.1.0 and then undeprecated it in 7.0.0-beta0, see [this discussion](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1361). So you can use `store.select` if you want as it's not deprecated in current ngrx versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Pipe** was introduced to RxJS in v5.5
to take code that looked like this:

```
of(1,2,3).map(x => x + 1).filter(x => x > 2);
```

and turn it into this

```
of(1,2,3).pipe(
  map(x => x + 1),
  filter(x => x > 2)
);
```

Same output, same concept but with different syntax.

It cleans up the 'observable.prototype' and makes the RxJS library more tree-shakeable, you only need to import what you use. It also makes it easier to write and use third-party operators.

Answer (score 2):

It´s considered best practice to use lettable operators. Because you can only import the specific operators you need into your project. The rest can be removed by tree shaking and so the bundle size is decreasing.

It seems a little bit weird in the beginning to use pipe with just one operator but you will get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing things.

> select is deprecated: from 6.1.0. Use the pipeable select operator
>   instead. (deprecation)tslint(1)

refers to the use of select outside of the `pipe`.

```
this.store.select( ... )
```

using `select` inside a `pipe` is the way to go.

```
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';

this.store.pipe(select( ... ))
```

is perfectly fine.